# WebView setWebViewClient() with Facebook Live Stream = ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, webview

I have a WebView with simple HTML of Facebook Live Stream :

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe allowfullscreen="true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="315" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fnico.up.9%2Fvideos%2F1895877650644648%2F&show_text=0&width=560" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="560"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I must override shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method of my WebView, so set a WebViewClient like this :

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.contains("mydomain.com")) {
            //I must do something in my app, without to load url
        } else {
            //else i want open native Android browser
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
        return true;//never to load the url in my webview
    }
});
```

The problem is if I have a Facebook Live Stream, I have a crash !

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=intent://video/?id={10155200044259063}&ref=m_embedded_video/ }
```

Effectively, Facebook's iframe want open the live in the Facebook native app with the custom uri intent://

**How I can treat this uri correctly ?!**

In my test :

- if I don't add my custom WebViewClient (never call setWebViewClient()), it's work perfectly !
- if I don't start new Activity and I return false, I have no crash, but I have view of Chrome error loading in the iframe : ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME !

---

### The most curios thing is :

- Why if I add just this simple line : `webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` I have ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, and if I remove it's work !!!?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you dont invoke setWebViewClient, does it load on your phone's default browser?

Comment: If I dont invoke setWebViewClient, all work fine : new url (http://) load on my phone's default browser, and url of Fb Live Stream (intent://) open in fb app.

Comment: and this is the behaviour that you want? (plus do something if the url is your own domain?)

Comment: Yes, I want open all url outside of my webview and I must do specific thing for a specific domain clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions

> Why if I add just this simple line : `webview.setWebViewClient(new
>   WebViewClient());` I have ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, and if I remove it's
>   work !!!?

Please take note that if you do not call `setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`, the WebView's default behaviour is to launch an application that handles URLs. Otherwise, setting the client using an instance of `WebViewClient` class will load URLs inside your `WebView` object.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

Thus, if you invoke `setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`, you are effectively executing a code similar to returning `false` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. Therefore giving you the same `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error.